# `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error with the following example when running the program.

The error reads as such:

```
burger.rb:8:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from burger.rb:19:in `new'
    from burger.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Any help is appreciated for this noob, the code is below:

```
$toppings = false

class Burger
    AVAILABLE_TOPPINGS = ["lettuce", "tomato", "onion", "cheese"]

    attr_reader :options

    def initialize
        @toppings = []
    end

    def order
        print "how many burgers would you like? "
        number = gets.chomp
        puts "#{number} burgers coming right up boss!"
    end
end

burger = Burger.new("lettuce")

burger.order
```

Comment: You are trying to pass an argument (`"lettuce"`) to an initializer that takes no arguments.

Comment: While the title is humorous, it won't help anyone understand what your question is about, which is important. Titles are used to help find questions when people do Internet searches, so having something more relevant to the question will help others find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the method `initialize` expects 0 argument, while you give it 1 (`"lettuce"` in `Burger.new("lettuce")`).

You need to make `initialize` expecting one argument:

```
def initialize(options)
    @toppings = []
    @options = options
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! - Like i said just starting out here. This makes sense. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said your initializer is expecting no arguments but you're giving it `lettuce`. If you're using ruby 2.1 or later I would suggest using keyword arguments:

```
class Burger
  TOPPINGS = %i[lettuce tomato onion cheese]

  attr_reader :toppings

  def initialize(toppings: [])
    @toppings = TOPPINGS & toppings
  end
end
```

This allows you do to `Burger.new(toppings: [:lettuce])` which I feel is a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$toppings = false
```

is code smell. Globals are generally not necessary, and should only be used when you're absolutely sure they're needed. When you're first learning an OO language I think it's better to avoid them and learn about variable scoping.

In this case, you don't use it in your sample code, but you do use:

```
@toppings = []
```

(which is again not used elsewhere). It isn't a good idea to name a global variable the same as an instance variable because it's too easy to use one when you mean the other, and introduce a bug.